# Is it possible to use an image fill in svg images that are loaded as a background?

Tags: css, svg, background-image, fill

Hi,

I am loading the following svg image as a background-image:

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="" viewBox="0 0 130 280" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="280px" height="130px">
 <pattern id="bg" height="280" width="130">
  <image xlink:href="back.png" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%"/>
 </pattern>
 <polyline points="121.67,271.958 121.67,276.671 122.91,277.994 126.135,277.994 125.97,265.177 121.587,272.123" id="e5_polyline" style="fill:'url(#bg)'; stroke-width: 1px;" stroke="#555555"/>
</svg>
```

This is my CSS:

```
background:url("images/global/polygon.svg") no-repeat 0 0;
width:130px;
height:280px;
```

the SVG lines load fine but not so the png image I want as the fill. What is wrong? Is it not possible to have an image as fill in this case? Or its a path problem? The png image is on the same folder as the SVG file so that path should be right.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `/back.png`? Also, does it work if you open the image directly?

Comment: I tried that but nothing. And it does load when I include the image directly and not as a background. Thats why I dont get it.

Comment: What if you just open that polygon.svg in the separate page?

Comment: I need it as the background.

Comment: remove the commas  `style="fill:url(#bg); stroke-width: 1px;"` and make sure that your polyline covers some surface , it seems to only show a dot from the stroke

Comment: I understand that. I've asked, does the image-to-fill load if you open the polygon.svg in the separate page.

Comment: at last, use a data-uri so it is there within the svg itself ....

Comment: to preserve user's privacy images must consist of a single file. So when you display SVG in an image context any embedded images cannot be external, they must be data URIs.

Comment: I removed the commas and no use. The polyline on my question is just a quick example. My actual one is bigger but still no background is shown. The image to fill opens fine everywhere, it even loads as the fill ONLY if the SVG is an element and not the background of some other element. How is data-uri used?

Comment: Do you mean by any chance that the png file must be encoded into base64? I read something about that.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Comment: A yes or no would have sufficed. If thats the case then SVG images are pretty much useless because embedding another file will make them much larger and that defeats the purpose of saving space. Besides I tried with base64 and that didnt work either.